# Vue method not accepting async/await

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am working on a Vue.js project where I am trying to run a series of promises depening on each other. To make this example simple I have cut out all but one and replaced the rest with a console.log which should output the value I am trying to access to then use later on. If I can get this example to work then the rest is just repeating it.

```
createBuilding: function() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(this.building === 'New building') {
          this.$store.dispatch('newBuilding', {
            address: this.address,
            number_units: this.number_units
          })
          .catch(err => {
            reject(err)
          })
          resolve(this.$store.getters.buildingID)
        } else {
          resolve(this.building)
        }
      }) 
    },
    onComplete: async function() {
      let buildingID = await this.createBuilding()
      console.log(buildingID)
      alert('Success');
    },
```

Real results:

I see the console.log fire off with undefined, then the alert then the awaited promise/function shows in the vue dev tools.

How can I get this so that I can get the result of the createBuilding method to use with my other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is promise constructor antipattern. There's no need to use `new Promise` in case a promise already exists and can be chained. The antipattern leaves the space for mistake, which is the case here.

`newBuilding` is expected to be asynchronous, but the promise is resolved instantly, this results in race condition.

It should be:

```
createBuilding() {
    if(this.building === 'New building') {
      return this.$store.dispatch('newBuilding',...)
      .then(() => this.$store.getters.buildingID)
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(this.building)
    }
},
```

With `async..await`, it's simplified to:

```
async createBuilding() {
    if(this.building === 'New building') {
      await this.$store.dispatch('newBuilding',...);
      return this.$store.getters.buildingID
    } else {
      return this.building
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a try and am seeing the getters firing off before anything else is including the await of the dispatch. I have searched my code to see if it was being called elsewhere and it's not. Any ideas why that might still be happening? I am also seeing the console.log of the buildingID firing off before the action actually happens.

Comment: *seeing the getters firing off before anything else is including the await of the dispatch* - how did you determine this? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. Could be a mistake in the action or anything else.

Comment: I am not sure how to reproduce the issue since I am not sure where the issue is coming from. Either way I think I solved it by making the actions async/await and doing an await on the axios.post A combo of your answer and the actions change seems to have solved it even though it introduced the weird getters error. As for determining how it was firing first, a ton of console.log and time stamps with descriptions